# How to remove related documents after removing by TTL?

Tags: mongodb

As part of my MongoDB, I have three different collections - `A`, `B` and `AtoB`.

`A` and `B` are different types of entities, where `AtoB` connects between them as follows-

A:

```
{
_id: ObjectId,
timestamp: Date,
keyA: string
}
```

B:

```
{
_id: ObjectId,
timestamp: Date,
keyB: number
}
```

AtoB:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  aId: ObjectId, // Points to a document from A
  bId: ObjectId // Points to a document from B
}
```

I created a TTL index on `A` documents - that will be deleted when the `timestamp` key is older than an hour.
Is it possible somehow to remove all the related `AtoB` documents, based on the removed `_id` property of the removed `A`s?

In other words, is it possible to not only remove the A documents using the TTL, but also remove the related documents of the ones the were removed?

Thanks

Comment: No. Also, the way the data is stored is very relational database like - not the way MongoDB's data needs to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

In a word - no, not in this set up.

The options you have:

- set up a changestream worker to delete links
- set up a cron job to clean up links collection every minute
- embed AtoB links into A documents

I would recommend the later, but it really depends on how feasible the change is for the rest of your application. Having a dedicated lookup collection is really a RDBS practice. It has very niche usecases in Mongo universe.

Your A documents will looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  timestamp: Date,
  keyA: string,
  bIds: [
    bId: ObjectId,
    bId: ObjectId,
    ....
  ] 
}
```

When the document's ttl expires the document is removed with all links at once.